# How to create auto increment series number using mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

code:

```
<?php
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('bugs');
    $where = "project_name = '".$project."'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $sql = $this->db->get();
    $res = $sql->num_rows();
    if($res === 0)
    {
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($bug as $row) 
        {
            echo $i;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($bug as $row) 
        {
            echo ++$i;
        }
    }
?>

$data = array(
        'project_name'=>$this->input->post('project'),
        'bug_id'=>$this->input->post('bug_id'),
        );
$query = $this->db->insert('bugs',$data);
```

In this code I have a table name bugs where I have a column i.e. bug_id. Now, I want to insert data into my table if table row having no value it insert bug_id = 1 and after that insert 2 and then 3 and so on. But now when I click on submit button it insert bug_id = 1 and then 2 but when I click on third it  insert again bug_id 2 . So, How can I fix this problem?Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has integrated AUTO_INCREMENT. Either you log into phpMyAdmin and change the properties of your bug_id field by clicking on edit, then selecting the "A_I" field.

Or you can do it with a SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE MODIFY bug_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

If @Twinfriends answer doesn't fit your needs (but that should be the correct way to do that, you shouldn't reinvent the wheel) then maybe the problem is with your:

```
   $data = array(
   'project_name'=>$this->input->post('project'),
   'bug_id'=>$this->input->post('bug_id'),
   );
   $query = $this->db->insert('bugs',$data);
```

Since you are actually using `$this->input->post('bug_id')` as your new id, maybe you want to use something else?

Where does your $bug var come from? To be sure of not getting duplicated ids or wrong one you could add to your MySql query something like "ORDER BY bug_id DESC LIMIT 1" (so that you take 1 row as result with the highest bug_id) and then just use that result + 1 as the new id